# Customizing Userback Widgets: How can I style the feedback widget to match my website's theme?

Tags: css

I want to customize the Userback feedback widget's appearance to match my website's theme and branding. What are the best practices for styling the Userback widget using CSS? Are there any limitations or considerations I should be aware of?

I have checked their website but not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just googled and Userback has a full widget customization section, considering you’re in a dev forum I assume you want to style it on the fly? This can be done with the JavaScript SDK, https://docs.userback.io/docs/javascript-sdk#widget_settings (https://docs.userback.io/docs/javascript-sdk#widget_settings) but I did notice you asked to “customize” the widget and this article says “edit” Create and Edit the Userback Widget